# Yii model sorting

Tags: sorting, activerecord, model, yii

How can I sort by PK in this case?

```
$model=new SupportTicket('search');
```

I can do that using search method inside the model, but I have to do that with object.
Sure I can rewrite standard method using DbCriteria, but probably easy way exists?

Answer (score 1):

On '**search()**' method, you can put:

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'id ASC';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use the find methods provided by CActiveRecord:

$model = SupportTicket::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'PK'));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` in your in `search()` model:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'sort' => array('defaultOrder' => 'id DESC'),
));
```